# Refresh all pivot tables in excel spreadsheet when data changes

Tags: excel, pivot, excel-2010, pivot-table

Does anyone know the VBA code to automatically refresh all Pivot tables (2 sheets that each hold 4 pivot tables) when data in the Excel (2010) spreadsheet is changed? It can also search for change in a specific cell.

Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

If your pivot tables are set up with absolute ranges throughout a workbook, I'm a fan of the simple approach:

```
Sub RefreshAllPivots()
' RefreshAllPivots Macro
' Refresh all the pivots in the workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't forget to format your code!

Answer (score 1):

this code added to the worksheet containing the source data should work

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet, Pivot As PivotTable
        For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            For Each Pivot In Sheet.PivotTables
                Pivot.RefreshTable
                Pivot.Update
        Next
    Next
End Sub`

For more info check
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I just tried this code but it doesn't seem to work. Placing it in the sheet containing the data doesn't do anything (a third sheet contains the data), nor does it work putting it in ThisWorkbook. Putting it on the first sheet where 4 pivot tables are placed, where a selection can be made, will result in an endless refresh loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you have data in the sheet called "data" and table is in sheet "pivot" with table named "PivotTable1", you can paste this on your data sheet vba tab.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    'If data on this worksheet changes, refresh the pivot table
    Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1").RefreshTable

End Sub
```